# Cassini with Windows 7 XP Mode

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-6, cassini, xp-mode

Is there a way to access the Cassini local web server from Windows 7's XP mode?

I'm developing on the Windows 7 host machine using Cassini, but would like to test in IE6 running inside the Windows XP guest.

Comment: might get a better response on serverfault

Comment: this is a developer question -- nobody else would care about Cassini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to access the Cassini server in the XP VM from within your Windows 7 host, then I don't believe so.

https://serverfault.com/questions/82899/can-i-access-cassini-from-a-remote-machine

If you have to access your website from your Host machine from within a VM, your best bet is to host it in IIS on the XP machine.

Or, if you're trying to access the site from within the XP Mode on your Windows 7 host O/S, you should spin up IIS on the Windows 7 machine and access it from XP - I think this is more what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I just released the CassiniDev 3.5.1/4.0.1 beta with a simple test fixture example if you are interested.

Full support for any IP.

Cassini for Developers and Testers: http://cassinidev.codeplex.com